# Let $g$ continous so that $\exists k>0$ so that $|g(x)|\le k\int_a^x|g| $ for all $x\in[a,b]$ Prove that $g(x)=0 $ for all $x\in[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Im trying to write a proof for this, but I don't know how to begin. Any help will be appreciated.

Let $g:[a,b]$ continous so that $\exists k>0$ : $|g(x)|\le k\int_a^x |g| $ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Prove that $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$

Comment: In the RHS, you have $k \int_a^x |g|(t) \ dt$. But what upper bound have you on $|g|(t)$? Plug it in the integral and see what happens.

Comment: I don't know, isn't $|g|$ bounded by the R.H.S? From above I mean

Comment: Yes! So, what does this yield?

Comment: That it has a supremum, but what can I do with it?

Comment: $|g|$ is also bounded from below by 0

Comment: anyone? I dont need you to solve it, just help me if you want

Answer (score 1):

Show by induction that $|g(x)| \le \frac{k^n}{n!} \int_a^x (t - a)^n |g(t)|\, dt$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and $n \in \Bbb N$. Let $g(x_0)$ be the maximum value of $g$ on $[a,b]$. Given $x\in [a,b]$,

$$|g(x)| \le \frac{k^n|g(x_0)|}{n!}\int_a^b (t - a)^n\, dt = \frac{|g(x_0)|}{k}\frac{[k(b - a)]^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty.$$

Therefore $g(x) = 0$.

---

Another way: Let $G(x) := \int_a^x |g(t)|\, dt$. Then $G'(x) = |g(x)| \le G(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Thus

$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x}G(x)) = e^{-x}G'(x) - e^{-x}G(x) \le 0,$$

showing that $e^{-x}G(x)$ is decreasing on $[a,b]$. Since $G(a) = 0$, we have that $e^{-x}G(x) \le e^{-a}G(a) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. This implies $G(x) = 0$ since $G(x)$ is nonnegative and $e^{-x}$ is positive. Therefore, $|g(x)| \le G(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, and consequently $g$ is identically $0$.

Comment: Sorry I need to solve it using theorems (like mean value for integrals, Fundamental theorem of calculus, etc)

Comment: @mobzopi what do you mean? The theorem that you need here is that a continuous function on a closed interval has a maximum.

Comment: Yes I know, I mean that I'm not allowed to prove it using induction

Comment: @mobzopi "Induction" _is_ just a theorem, namely that if $P_a$ and $P_k \to P_{k+1} \forall k$, then $P_n \forall n>a$.

Comment: @AJMansfield yeah I know, but  I have to prove it using only theorems shown in class(Spivak based)

Comment: @kobe The proof is right, thanks, but I need to prove it using only theorems found in Spivak Chapter 13 and 14(Riemann integral)

Comment: @mobzopi you should've been more specific and given more information about what you can use. I do not carry the book, so I cannot use that as a reference for what is allowed. Can you use partitions? Does Spivak cover integrals before derivatives? Please give more info.

Comment: @mobzopi also, didn't you say the fundamental theorem of calculus is allowed? I used that to get $G'(x) = |g(x)|$.

Comment: @kobe yes, sory I wasn't more specific. I'm allowed to use partitions,fundamental theorem of calculus, mean value for integrals, cauchy inequality for integrals,etc.; but I'm not allowed to use the exponential function(we haven't defined it yet) . Spivak defines derivatives and continuity before integrals,but defines logarithm and exponential functions until the end of the book.